# Number of ways to give 3 people 2 cards so that each gets at least one ace

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose 3 people are each dealt 2 cards from one standard deck of playing cards. You may assume that
>   the order in which the cards are dealt does not matter. In how many ways can the cards be dealt so that
>   everyone gets at least one ace?

So there are 4 different ways to pick the first ace, then 3 for the second, and 2 for the third.

So $4\times3\times2$

Then $\binom{49}{3}$ ways to pick 3 more cards to distribute, and 3! ways to distribute them.

So I get $4(3)(2)\binom{49}{3}3! = 2653056$ but the answer I'm given is $2571840$ so I'm clearly over counting somehow, I'm guessing it has to do with how the last ace is distributed? How do I handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Case I**, nobody gets the fourth ace.  The number of distributions is
$$4\times3\times2\times48\times47\times46\ .$$

**Case II**, all four aces are received.  Begin by choosing who gets two aces, and which two he gets.  The number of distributions is
$$3\times6\times2\times48\times47\ .$$

The total is
$$3\times2\times48\times47\times(4\times46+6)=2571840\ .$$